# Reminders, macOS Ventura and MS Exchange

Tags: reminders, exchange, ventura

Since the upgrade to Ventura, I am unable to see my Reminders from an MS Exchange account any more.

The account is configured:

[image: Account settings screenshot]

But no list or task is shown:

[image: Reminders screenshot]

Any idea what I could try to get them back?

Comment: I found that removing the account and re-adding it often fixed issues like this.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it's still empty. I have the this situation on two Ventura machines (a Mac Mini Intel and an M1 MacBook Pro). On a VM with Ventura it's working. On Monterey and iOS is also working ...

Comment: Apple software and MS Servers don't always work and play nice together. I fought issues like these for years and the only reliable solution (that worked *most* of the time) is to switch to Outlook on Mac/iPhone/iPad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following:

- Disabled the reminders in the Exchange account and then re-enabled it: no changes
- Completely deleted the Exchange account (with data) and re-added it

  - **The reminders are there again (solved)**
  - The calendar took four hours to reappear (no data) but is there again
  - I had several problems with email (a local folder with 40'000 empty messages appeared, I had to reboot because my account was used by another app?) but in the end everything seem to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here since updating to Ventura. The good thing about the situation is that it's obviously a general problem affecting plenty of people, so I am optimistic there will be a fix eventually.

As I didn't want to use Outlook (a bit overblown for a temporary reminder fix), I added my exchange account to Microsoft To Do, which is a small piece of software that is available at no cost on the macOS App Store.

BTW: delegated Exchange calenders stopped synching after updating to Ventura as well; that problem I was able to fix by completely resetting macOS Calendar and then re-adding the various accounts and delegations.

--

[UPDATE] Matteo's solution (thank you!) of completely removing the Exchange account with all its data and then re-adding it worked for me as well. Pretty painful having to download 90K+ email messages again but at least everything is synching as it's supposed to afterwards.